# How to load an inconsistent CSV file using sql loader?

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have the below sample csv file

```
,,,Test File,
,todays Date:,01/10/2018,Generation date,10/01/2019 11:20:58
Header 1,Header 2,Header 3,Header 4,Header 5
,My account no,100102GFC,,
A,B,C,D,E
A,B,C,D,E
A,B,C,D,E
```

Below is my table structure

```
Todays Date,My account,Header 1,Header 2,Header 3,Header 4,Header 5
01/10/2018,100102GFC,A,B,C,D,E
01/10/2018,100102GFC,A,B,C,D,E
01/10/2018,100102GFC,A,B,C,D,E
```

I am having issues in getting the todays date from second line of my file and account no from the 4th line of the file. The first four line will be consistent. My actual data starts from 5th line.

Is it possible to get a particular from the 2nd and 4th line and load it along with other values starting from 5th line? how do we handle this in the control file?

Comment: If this was SQL Server I would just load each row into a single varchar field then split it using T-SQL. Not sure if you can do this in Oracle.

Comment: If you know that just the second and fourth line are broken, edit these lines out of the file, only import the rest and manually add the troublemakers.

Comment: SQL Loader lets you skip the first 4 four lines - is that what you are asking for?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no, i need to take value from the 2nd and 4th line and then only skip the first 4 lines. I need to append date and account number along with the rest of data

Comment: You will need to write a shell script (or batch file) that first extracts those values, then adjust the control file, then skip the first lines. If `todays date` is always "todays" date, then you could simply use `sysdate` as a default value for that column.

Comment: i am currently manipulating the csv file using shell script to bring it to desired format and then will upload it , thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally load records into different tables. So you can achieve this effect by:

- Creating three staging tables: the load date, the account date, and the load data
- Loading the records into the appropriate table
- Cross joining the result to get your output

For example, create these staging tables:

```
create table t (
  c1 varchar2(1),
  c2 varchar2(1),
  c3 varchar2(1),
  c4 varchar2(1),
  c5 varchar2(1)
);

create table dt (
  load_date date
);

create table act (
  acct# varchar2(20)
);
```

Then use the following control file to state when to load which records into each table:

```
LOAD DATA
infile *
TRUNCATE 
INTO TABLE dt WHEN (2:13) = 'todays Date:'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
DATE FORMAT "DD/MM/YYYY"
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
c1 filler, c2 filler, load_date date, c4 filler, c5 filler
)
INTO TABLE act WHEN (2:14) = 'My account no'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
c1 filler position(1:1), c2 filler, acct#, c4 filler, c5 filler
)
INTO TABLE t WHEN (1:1) <> ','
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
c1 position(1), c2, c3, c4, c5 
)
BEGINDATA
,,,Test File,
,todays Date:,01/10/2018,Generation date,10/01/2019 11:20:58
Header 1,Header 2,Header 3,Header 4,Header 5
,My account no,100102GFC,,
A,B,C,D,E
A,B,C,D,E
A,B,C,D,E
```

The when clauses use positional notation to check for given characters. Adjust as necessary. Filler in the column clauses means ignore this field.

Now load it:

```
sqlldr userid=chris/chris@db control=sqlldr.ctl

SQL*Loader: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Mon Jan 14 10:56:40 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Path used:      Conventional
Commit point reached - logical record count 7

Table DT:
  1 Row successfully loaded.

Table ACT:
  1 Row successfully loaded.

Table T:
  3 Rows successfully loaded.

Check the log file:
  sqlldr.log
for more information about the load.
```

All you have to do is cross join these all together to get your desired result:

```
select * from dt
cross  join act
cross  join t;

LOAD_DATE           ACCT#       C1   C2   C3   C4   C5   
01-OCT-2018 00:00   100102GFC   A    B    C    D    E    
01-OCT-2018 00:00   100102GFC   A    B    C    D    E    
01-OCT-2018 00:00   100102GFC   A    B    C    D    E
```

This is a bit messy. If you're able to transfer the file to the database server, it would be easier to use external tables.

Comment: Hey!! thanks for the solution..this i had thought about, but we would require a unique key in all the 3 table, that can be joined. we would be requiring to store the data every day. Hence it will be fine for a single load, however for the next load it will give wrong impression, is it possible to have a unique identifier in all table? if so, how?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at. The idea is you load the data into three temporary tables. Then load it into the real table.

Comment: ohh.. i understood now..The 3 tables will always be truncated for the next load.. and main table will  have the actual data.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A common way to handle loads also is to load all rows into a staging table.  For instance you could create a staging table with 5 varchar2 columns (the largest number of columns in the data).  Truncate and load all rows as-is into the staging table.

[image]

Then create a PL/SQL script to run next that loads the data from the staging table into the production tables, performing validations and transforms on the way in. Make this a stored procedure.

```
declare
  save_date date;
  save_acct_nbr varchar2(10);
begin

    execute immediate 'truncate table x_test';

    -- Save the file date
    select to_date(col3, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    into save_date
    from X_TEST_STG
    where col2 = 'todays Date:';

    -- Save the account number
    select col3
    into save_acct_nbr
    from X_TEST_STG
    where col2 = 'My account no';

    insert into x_test
    (select save_date, save_acct_nbr, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
     from X_TEST_STG
     where col1 is not null
     and col1 != 'Header 1');

    commit;
end;
```

Badda Bing, Badda Boom!

[image]